# Working with a base class and have classes that inherite from it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-2.2, base-class

I have a base class :

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Class that inherite from BaseClass :

```
public class InheriteClass : BaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

So the first view you need to fill in your "Name" and "LastName", then click next and you go to another view with more fields.

But when I click in this view on the "Submit" button the properties "Name" and LastName" are null...

First page "Next" button :

```
    public IActionResult GoToCategoryView(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("NextView", baseClass);
    }
```

The next view has :

```
@model InheritanceClass
```

And when I click the "Submit" button :

```
    public IActionResult SubmitThis(InheritanceClass inheritanceClass )
    {
        var testClass = new testClass
        {
            Name = inheritanceClass.Name,
            LastName = inheritanceClass.LastName,
            MyProperty = inheritanceClass.MyProperty
        };

        return View(testClass);
    }
```

**UPDATE**
With clearer sample. In the above sample "Name" and "LastName" are null.

Comment: Don't forget the base() keyword for your InheritanceClass!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base

Comment: Where are you submitting the data? Will you include the controller action to where you are submitting? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this could compile, seeing as you are accessing `baseClass.MyProperty`, which doesn't exist. Are you sure your example is accurate?

Comment: @JohnWu updated my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking an action via a request is *not* the same thing as just calling a method on a class. In the latter situation, you already have an `InheritanceClass` in memory, and you're simply upcasting it to `BaseClass`. Then, of course, later you can downcast it back to an `InheritanceClass`, because that's what it is.

For an action, the param is being provided from the request, which is just unstructured, unbound data. A modelbinder is employed to attempt to "bind" that data to an actual structured type. In order to do that, it looks at the type of the param and instantiates *that* type (i.e. `BaseClass`). Then, it maps data over from the request on to appropriate properties on that class instance. Importantly, though, `BaseClass` doesn't have a `MyProperty` property, so the modelbinder will *discard* that value. What you have at the end is just a `BaseClass` instance, because that's the type of the param. You can downcast to `InheritanceClass`, if you like, but any properties specific to `InheritanceClass` will be null or default, because they don't exist on `BaseClass`.

Long and short, you can't bind to base classes in actions. Anything not on the base class will be discarded. If you need `InheritanceClass`, then you must bind to `InheritanceClass`.

Comment: I see, so in my case its best to just make one Class and use the same Class on both Views?

Comment: Yes. Essentially. You can also create a separate view model that encompasses all the properties of the various subtypes and then map to the appropriate subtype, depending on the data (which properties have values, etc.). The main point is that the class you bind to needs to have properties for any and all data coming from the post. It can have more properties, but not less, or data will be discarded.

Comment: Hmm I switched to one class and pass that to the next View but it also loses the values of "Name" and "LastName".